# How can I solve the problem with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I started developing my spring boot application and faced a problem with thymeleaf.

**TaskController.java**

```
@Controller
public class TaskController {

    @GetMapping({"/index"})
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "Augustine");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Thymeleaf Spring Boot</h1>
<h2>
    <span>Hello, <th:block th:text="${name}">[name]</th:block></span>
</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**application.properties**

```
# setup server port
server.port=8080
# setup a default suffix
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
# setup thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
```

A part of **pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Result**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrHzY.png

Here is **folders and files structure**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWJ3i.png

If I put index.html into *resources/templates/*, I have an issue following
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZroA.png

So how could I solve this problem? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3684747 yes, it does not help anyway

Comment: I just copied your code to a new Spring boot project and it works fine if I put the index.html in **src/main/resources/templates** like you did according to your last paragraph. Do you have any other relevant code/properties that are necessary to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @g00glen00b it's so weird. As you can see, there is a config file, repository and one more html file. I also have more dependecies in pom.xml, but they do not influence my index.html

Comment: if your `index.html` is in the `main/resources/static` folder, then you should put `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/static/` in the application.properties

Comment: @DirkDeyne omg it is so obvious, it really works, you saved my day ^_^

Comment: I don't think Thymeleaf templates should be placed in `static` - that is for directly accessible resources such as image files, CSS, JS, etc. Thymeleaf templates are intended to only exist on the server and not be visible to the browser.

Comment: If it now suddenly works by changing the `spring.thymeleaf.prefix`, then there probably was an issue within VSCode itself because as I mentioned this should have worked when you used the templates-folder. And as andrewJames mentioned, using the templates-folder is prefered.

Comment: @Kirill how did you access your page? By `http://localhost:8080/index` or `http://localhost:8080/index.html`. That would explain why got the raw page (index.html in static folder) and the error-page when (index.html in templates). So move index.html to templates folder, and access page via `localhost:8080/index` (with: spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/)

Comment: @DirkDeyne I actually dont know why, but I put HTML files in templates and set spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/ and you know what?) It works. However 6 hours ago it does not work at all

Comment: @g00glen00b I'm sure that was VScode's problem, thank you for your advices